# Convert MultiPart Message into XML/HL7 using Custom Send Pipeline inside Orchestartion

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

In my Project, I am using custom a send pipeline inside orchestration to convert MultiPart message into HL7 message, so that I can log Raw HL7 message into DB , by the next step in orchestration.

In Custom Pipeline, I used BTAHL7 2.x Assembler, which assembles the Multipart message and converts into XML messgae.

Using the below code in Message Assignment: called the custom pipeline to covert Multipart nessage into XML.

```
XMLResponse = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteSendPipeline(
typeof(BTAHL7Schemas.SendPipeline1),MultiPartMsg,XMLResponse);
```

But the above code  throws

> error: "Body Schema Missing"

If am successful in the above step, I can easily convert XML into HL7 string.

How can I do this?